# Capture bandwidth usage from remote machine across time

Tags: linux, networking, bandwidth, iftop

I would like to capture the bandwidth usage to and from one specific remote machine across time on my system. `iftop` command is definitely one option, which gives the network usage, and has filtering , but I need to parse the text output to get the incoming bandwidth usage and outgoing bandwidth usage.

```
sudo iftop -t -s 2 -f "src host <remote_machine_ip>"
```

My current plan is to run the above command in a loop, parse the text output each time and append to a csv file `(current_time, transmitted, received)`.

Is there a better alternative ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/327577/how-to-gather-full-network-usage-statistics-on-a-freebsd-router/327585#327585

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the "sar" tool, which periodically collects network, cpu, memory, and other resource data and stores it for later use?  I believe most distributions have a 10-minute delay between polls to avoid being to intrusive, and storing too much data.

On my RHEL box I simply installed the "sysstat" RPM which provides the /usr/bin/sar command and waited a few minutes for data to be collected.  Then I could review the data like this:

P.S.  You can reconfigure the polling frequency by adjusting the crontab file in /etc/cron.d/sysstat

P.P.S.  The sar data is kept for 30 days by default.  You can review older data by telling sar what file to use with the "-f /var/log/sa/saXY" argument where XY is the two-digit day you're interested in (e.g. 12)

```
[jcall@nas ~]$ sar -n DEV | grep enp4s0
12:10:01 AM    enp4s0      4.86      2.33      1.06      0.25      0.00      0.00      1.11
12:20:01 AM    enp4s0      4.70      2.32      1.05      0.26      0.00      0.00      1.07
12:30:01 AM    enp4s0      4.73      2.25      1.06      0.27      0.00      0.00      1.01
12:40:01 AM    enp4s0      5.32      2.76      1.49      0.39      0.00      0.00      0.97
12:50:01 AM    enp4s0      4.57      2.22      1.01      0.25      0.00      0.00      0.90
01:00:01 AM    enp4s0      4.71      2.32      1.02      0.27      0.00      0.00      1.08
01:10:01 AM    enp4s0      4.60      2.29      1.03      0.28      0.00      0.00      0.97
01:20:01 AM    enp4s0      4.63      2.21      1.04      0.26      0.00      0.00      0.94
01:30:01 AM    enp4s0      4.68      2.18      1.07      0.25      0.00      0.00      0.97
01:40:01 AM    enp4s0      4.70      2.20      1.08      0.25      0.00      0.00      0.99
01:50:01 AM    enp4s0     10.28      2.72      1.43      0.35      0.00      0.00      0.88
02:00:01 AM    enp4s0      4.69      2.29      1.02      0.27      0.00      0.00      1.05
02:10:01 AM    enp4s0      4.80      2.26      1.08      0.25      0.00      0.00      1.03
02:20:01 AM    enp4s0      4.77      2.26      1.08      0.26      0.00      0.00      0.96
02:30:01 AM    enp4s0      4.96      2.42      1.09      0.33      0.00      0.00      0.97
02:40:01 AM    enp4s0      4.99      2.37      1.06      0.32      0.00      0.00      1.08
Average:       enp4s0      5.13      2.34      1.10      0.28      0.00      0.00      1.00
```